# the arguments of CefV8Handler callback function Execute is invalid

Tags: javascript, c++, windows, chromium-embedded

I use CEF web browser kernel to replace IE browser ActivcX for support cross platform.

Yesterday, I post a thread for asking support Javascript callback method `window.external.xxx` in CEF framework. [How can I support window.external.xxx in cef framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42503265/how-can-i-support-window-external-xxx-in-cef-framework)

and Czarek Tomczak's sample code solved my problem. thanks Czarek Tomczak.

now, the Javascript function can call my C++ funcion. But I count another problem. when I recieve the CefV8handler Execute callback function.

```
virtual bool Execute(const CefString& name, CefRefPtr<CefV8Value> object, const CefV8ValueList& arguments, CefRefPtr<CefV8Value>& retval, CefString& exception);
```

I figure out that the name and the object parameters contain values, but the arguments parameter doesn't.

my javascript code is like that

```
<script>
        function test() {
            alert(window.external.testlibcef("111111111"));
        }
</script>
```

the code in CefRenderProcessHandler function OnContextCreated is like that

```
CefRefPtr<CefV8Value> ptrGlobalObj = context->GetGlobal();
CefRefPtr<CefV8Value> ptrExternal = CefV8Value::CreateObject(NULL);
CefRefPtr<CefV8Handler> ptrV8Handler = new TcCefV8Handler();
CefRefPtr<CefV8Value> jsTestlibcef = CefV8Value::CreateFunction(_T("testlibcef"), ptrV8Handler);
ptrExternal->SetValue(_T("testlibcef"), jsTestlibcef, V8_PROPERTY_ATTRIBUTE_NONE);
ptrGlobalObj->SetValue("external", ptrExternal, V8_PROPERTY_ATTRIBUTE_NONE);
```

Is there anything I missed up?

Comment: 'Arguments' has to contain a list of arguments. Are you sure it doesn't? How did you test it? btw you should keep in mind that CefV8Handler is executed in the renderer process. It means its code has to communicate with the main browser process somehow.

Comment: @alexeibs I run a http server which I code by golang. I let my cef browser load the page and click a button on the page. the button will response the onclick event and call my c++ function. I use the cefsimple project which I download from the cef office site. I change some code to load my test page. It works well.

Comment: @alexeibs my project is based on MFC framework. at beginning, I thought  it will cause by the MFC framework. So I change the cefsimple sample from base WinSDK to MFC framework(base on a dialog). But it still works well. So, I don't know what's the matter. There is a very strange scenario is that the five arguments of the execute callback function, just the arguments is wrong, the others is ok.

Comment: Your http server has nothing to do with it. I meant multiprocess architecture of Chromium. You didn't answer my question "How did you test it". Did you attach debugger to the renderer process? I'm asking because I did use CEF JS integration myself and my V8Handler worked as expected.

Comment: @alexeibs Thanks for your answering. I have solved the issue. I used release cef dll and cef_dll_wrapper static lib in my debug environment. But I still don't know why. I build release exe file to testing it that I didn't do before. And it works well. So I replace the cef library whit debug edition in my debug environment. what a mistake.